# JLayered Pane does not display images properly

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, jlayeredpane

For some reason, only 1/5 (or less) of each image is displayed. Since it is a Layered Pane at least 1 should be fully displayed. Layout is null because this is a learning program
Why is this happening?

Here is the code:
Class test1

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;


public class test extends JPanel
{
    private JFrame frame=new JFrame("");
    private JLayeredPane layered =new JLayeredPane();
    private BufferedImage image;
    private test2 image2=new test2();



    public test()
    {
         try
        {               
       image=ImageIO.read(new File("im1.png"));    

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            //Nothing
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }

    public void draw()
    {
        frame.setLayout(null);
        image2.setLayout(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setSize(800,800);
        frame.add(layered);
        this.setBounds(30,50,70,80);
        layered.add(this,new Integer(1));
        image2.setBounds(100,120,170,400);
        layered.add(image2,new Integer(1000));
        frame.setContentPane(layered);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
   }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
    }
    public static void main()
    {
        test t=new test();
        t.draw();
    }
}
```

Class test2

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;


public class test2 extends JPanel
{
    private JPanel thepanel=new JPanel();;
    private BufferedImage image2;



    public test2()
    {
      try{image2=ImageIO.read(new File("im2.png"));}
      catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {    super.paintComponent(g);
       g.drawImage(image2,0,0,this);
  }
 }
```

I also do not get what setOpaque(true/false) exactly is and when it is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `1/5` of each image is displayed as you're using a `null` layout and and setting the bounds of the containers that paint the images to sizes smaller then the images

```
this.setBounds(30,50,70,80);
```

and

```
image2.setBounds(100,120,170,400);
```

Use a [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), add the `JPanels` `test` and `test2` to the `JFrame` and invoke `JFrame#pack`. Ensure that both panels have a preferred size by overriding `getPreferredSize`.

Aside: Java naming conventions show that class names start with *uppercase* letters such as `Test` and `Test2`.

Answer (score 0):

`setOpaque(false)` basically will remove the background of the `Jcomponent`, essentially making it have no background, so if you have one component on top of another then by called setOpaque on the top component will make the bottom visible

[Check out this](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/setopaque.html) for more detailed information on what setOpaque() does